# I am having problem with the error class undeclared in scope

Tags: c++

I am compiling these programs. Complex.h, Complex.cpp, and project1_task1.cpp on centOS I compile this fine in visual studio, but I get the error in centOS. this is for a class.

Complex.h

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

class Complex
{
private:
    double realPart;
    double imaginaryPart;
public:
    Complex(double real = 0, double imag = 0); //constructor that initializes the complex number by default arguments
    double getReal(); //get function that returns the real part of the complex number
    double getImag(); //get function that returns the imaginary part of the complex number
    void setReal(double real); //set function that sets the real part of the complex number
    void setImag(double imag); //set function that sets the imaginary part of the complex number
    void print(); //function that displays the complex number
    
};

#endif
```

Complex.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.h"

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex(double real, double imag)
{
    realPart = real;
    imaginaryPart = imag;
}

double Complex::getReal() {
    return this->realPart;
}


double Complex::getImag() {
    return this->imaginaryPart;
}

void Complex::setReal(double real) {
    realPart = real;
}


void Complex::setImag(double imag) {
    imaginaryPart = imag;
}

void Complex::print() {
    if (realPart != 0)
        cout << realPart;
    if (imaginaryPart != 0)
    {
        if (imaginaryPart == 1)
            cout << "+i";
        else if (imaginaryPart == -1)
            cout << "-i";
        else if (imaginaryPart > 0 && realPart != 0)
            cout << " + " << imaginaryPart << "i";
        else
            cout << imaginaryPart << "i";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

here is project1_task1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include"complex.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Complex c;
    c.setReal(2);
    c.setImag(3);
    c.print();

    Complex c1(4);
    c1.setImag(5);
    c1.print();

    Complex c2(6, 7);
    c2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting Complex not defined in project1_task1.cpp when I compile in centOs.

how can I fix this?

Comment: Is the filename complex.h or Complex.h?  Linux filesystems are usually case-sensitive.

Comment: Should be Complex.h and Complex.cpp

Comment: Then your `#include` line is wrong in project1_task1.cpp

Comment: There should also be an error then about file not found, although perhaps different files exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since linux filesystem are usually case sensitive, then do in

```
project1_task1.cpp
```

replace the

```
#include"complex.h"
```

with

```
#include"Complex.h"
```